# Delete a comment by Graph API from fb:comments posted by an user? Yes, again

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fbml

Because a moderator has deleted the same point on the same topic, i open a new question (yes, is stupid to do it, but i don't make the rules)

I have a comment box with fb:comments, but the new api doesn't have a way to delete a comment, so, is it possible with Graph api? Scraly, was posted on the same topic that is a way to do that, but i want to know how to do it.

I hope that this time this message will not be deleted, because there is no reason again to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Graph API for this:

if the comment has the id 1234567 you can delete the comment by issueing a delete request:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/1234567?method=delete&access_token=...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i get an error using that: 

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#200) Users can only delete their own comments"
   }
}

Comment: Can you try this using an application access token rather than a user access token?

Comment: Hey, i thought that access token was the application, i'll try with the user, perhaps that is the problem. But, can i get the access token from the user?

Comment: Nevermind, i see how to get the access token from a user. Thanks!!

Comment: It's not working using either access_token from the user, or the access_token from the application. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, I just tried this and it's working fine for me. Which query/request are you using?

Comment: This is the query https://graph.facebook.com/10150344442237814_19194109?method=delete&access_token=111285118965654|MI_VkYPpdoXViPdrnctluHsjJjs and you can see the message here: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://www.nightphotosfever.com/mispruebas/albums/album.php?user=1437242602

Comment: @Inga H what you suggested works fine when i am deleting my comments...but it throws an error when i am trying to delete comments by other users. I should be able to delete others comments since I am the admin?? The error thrown is: { "error": { "type": "OAuthException", "message": "(#200) Users can only delete their own comments" } }

Answer (score 0):

as ingah-h said before you can delete a comment by it's id
using the following endpoint:

```
   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{comment-id}?method=delete
```

and be aware to pass your page access token with the request as a header

Authorization: "OAuth EAADhsxfbE8sBAG02xoKNH1nMt....."